# My Sencha code keeps on asking me to put a comma

Tags: extjs, touch

Ext.define('GoV.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

```
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Welcome',
            iconCls: 'home',

            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Mobile App: Government of Vanuatu'
            },

            html: [
                '<img src ="resources/icons/logogov.png"/>',
                '<h4>Constitution of the Republic of Vanuatu</h4>',
                '<p>Constitution of the Republic of Vanuatu</p>'
            ].join("")
        },
        {
            title: 'Read',
            iconCls: 'action',

             styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            items: 
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'constitution',
                    html: 
                        '<h1>Constitution: Part One</h1>'
                }

}
```

});-------------> this is the point that keeps on asking  me to put a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ] of 'items' ? Meaning the array of items (directly in the config-dictionary is not ending and he expect more values)

Replace

```
    }
    });
```

With

```
    }]
    });
```

Beside that, I think you are missing an } as well, this is not that hard to find when you try to make the format more readable and try to strip back to the basic elements by eliminating the sub-childs.

Comment: I can't vote because stack overflow wants me to have 15 reputation. I will when I reach 15 reputation.